# Cannot install Windows System Resource Manager, must specify installation type

Tags: performance, windows-server-2012, resource-management

When I try to install Windows System Resource manager
downloadable from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8120
on Windows Server 2012 R2, I get this dialog

[image: dialog]

and when I click next, I get the error message

> An installation type must be specified before Windows System Resource
> Manager can be installed.
> Specify an installation type.

Why?

(I have checked and I have at least 30 KB on my hard drive)

Comment: Expand *Server and Client*, and [edit] your question to include a more detailed screenshot.  The download doesn’t appear to be compatible with Windows Server 2012R2

Comment: There seems to be nothing under Server and Client. Maybe you are right about incompatibility, but there is no error message indicating that.

Comment: The download page indicates the system requirements for the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to install Windows System Resource manager downloadable from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8120 on Windows Server 2012 R2, I get this dialog

Windows System Resource Manager was deprecated with the release of Windows Server 2012.  Windows Server 2012R2 doesn’t support WSRM.

> Windows System Resource Manager (WSRM) is deprecated beginning with Windows Server® 2012. You should begin planning now to use alternate methods for any applications, code, or scenarios that depend on this feature.

[Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh997019(v=ws.11))